# A way for dealing with stiff ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods

Let us considered the following ODEs
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{dX}{dt} = F(X), \tag{1.1}
\end{align*}
where the unknown $X\in \mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^l$ and it can be stiff. These ODEs can be solved numerically by classical Newton's method if $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere on the considered domain
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{X^{n+1}-X^n}{\Delta t} = F\left(X^{n+1}\right).
\end{align*}
In cases of $F$ is not differentiable everywhere, I have read in a lecture that there is a way to solve numerically by replacing the system (1.1) with the following system
\begin{align*}
    X^{n+1} - X^n - (1-\nu)\Delta t F(X^{n+1}) & = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^l\tag{1.2a}\\
    \det\left[I - (1-\nu)\Delta t \nabla F(X^{n+1}) \right] - w &= 0 \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1.2b} \\
    \min(\nu,w) &= 0 \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1.2c}
\end{align*}
where $\nu$ and $w$ are two new unknowns to be sought for simultaneously to $X^{n+1}$. I wonder how they can do like this and what is technique they use?

Comment: You might get better guidance in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com.